# R parallel package - error is passing the arguments for Task parellization

Tags: r, parallel-processing, package

I have a sample function `ratio_sim_vec(x1, x2, nrep = 1000)` that returns ratio of means of `x1` and `x2` after runnnig bootstrapping algorith. I like to improve it now by runnnig it on multiple clusters.

Here is the code I have and I'm getting foolowing error:

> `Error in clusterExport(cl, ratio_sim_vec, x1, x2, nrep): unused arguments (x2, nrep)`

```r
ratio_sim_par <- function(x1, x2, nrep = 1000) {

        # Initiate cluster
        cl <- makeCluster(7)

        clusterExport(cl, ratio_sim_vec, x1, x2, nrep) # to export the current state of the whole R master session

        calls <- list("ratio_sim_vec", list(x1, x2, nrep)) 

        Tboot <- parSapply(cl,
              calls,
              function(call) {
                do.call(call[[1]])
              })

        stopCluster(cl)

        return(Tboot)

}

bpar <- ratio_sim_par(x1, x2, 10) #0000)
Error in clusterExport(cl, ratio_sim_vec, x1, x2, nrep): unused arguments (x2, nrep)
```

Can someone please point the mistake I'm doing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using this solved the issue:

```
clusterExport(cl, varlist=c("x1", "x2", "nrep"), envir=environment())
```